# Split multiple CSV cell values from multiple columns using Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to split multiple values in a CSV cell. I can do it right if the multiple values in a cell is found in a single column only, but I'm having difficulty doing it if the multiple values are found in multiple columns. Any guidance will be appreciated.

Here's the sample of the data I'm trying to split:

```
| Column A              | Column B               |
|Value1, Value2, Value3 | Value3, Value4, Value5 |
|Value6                 | Value7, Value8         |
```

I'm aiming to have a result like this:

```
| Column A | Column B |
| Value1   | Value3   |
| Value2   | Value4   |
| Value3   | Value5   |
| Value6   | Value7   |
| Value6   | Value8   |
```

Here's my code:

```
require 'csv'

split_a = []
split_b = []

def split_values(value)
  value = value.to_s
  value = value.gsub('/', ',').gsub('|', ',').gsub(' ', ',')
  return value.split(',').map(&:strip)
end

source_csv = kendo_shipment = CSV.read('source_file.csv', headers: true, header_converters: :symbol, liberal_parsing: true).map(&:to_h)

source_csv.each do |source_csv|
  column_a = source_csv[:column_a]
  column_b = source_csv[:column_b]
  column_a = split_values(column_a)
  column_a.each do |column_a|
    next if column_a.nil? || column_a.empty?

    split_a << [
      column_a: column_a,
      column_b: column_b
    ]
  end
end

split_a.each do |key, split_a|
  column_a = key[:column_a]
  column_b = key[:column_b]
  column_b = split_values(column_b)
  column_b.each do |column_b|
    next if column_b.nil? || column_b.empty?

    split_b << [
      column_a,
      column_b
    ]
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you going to write it back to a CSV file? What kind of output do you want to get two arrays or a hash or something else?

Comment: Yes, writing it back to CSV file

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```rb
require 'csv'

source_csv = CSV.read('source_file.csv',
  col_sep: '|',
  headers: true,
  header_converters: lambda {|h| h.strip},
  liberal_parsing: true
)
COLUMN_NAMES = ['Column A', 'Column B']

# Column values
columns = COLUMN_NAMES.map do |col_name|
  source_csv&.map do |row|
    row[col_name]&.split(',')&.map(&:strip)
  end&.flatten(1) || []
end

# repeat the last value in case the number of values in the columns differs:
vals_last_id = columns.map {|col| col.count}.max - 1
columns.each do |col|
  # replace `col.last` with `nil` on the next line if you want to leave the value blank
  col.fill(col.last, col.length..vals_last_id) if col.length <= vals_last_id
end

values = columns[0].zip(*columns[1..-1])
# result:
pp values; 1
# [["Value1", "Value3"],
#  ["Value2", "Value4"],
#  ["Value3", "Value5"],
#  ["Value6", "Value7"],
#  ["Value6", "Value8"]]
```

Generate **CSV** text, with `|` (pipe) delimiter instead comma:

```rb
csv = CSV.new( '',
  col_sep: '|',
  headers: COLUMN_NAMES,
  write_headers: true
);
values.each {|row| csv << row};
puts csv.string
# Column A|Column B
# Value1|Value3
# Value2|Value4
# Value3|Value5
# Value6|Value7
# Value6|Value8
```

Formatted output:

```rb
col_val = [COLUMN_NAMES] + values
col_widths = (0..(COLUMN_NAMES.count - 1)).map do |col_id|
  col_val.map {|row| row[col_id]&.length || 0}.max
end
fmt = "|" + col_widths.map {|w| " %-#{w}s "}.join('|') + "|\n"
col_val.each {|row| printf fmt % row}; 1
# | Column A | Column B |
# | Value1   | Value3   |
# | Value2   | Value4   |
# | Value3   | Value5   |
# | Value6   | Value7   |
# | Value6   | Value8   |
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a special option to define a column separator `col_sep: '|'` it simplifies the code.

```rb
require 'csv'

source_csv = CSV.read('source_file.csv', col_sep: '|', headers: true, header_converters: :symbol, liberal_parsing: true)

split_a = []
split_b = []

# I just assign values to separate arrays, because I am not sure what kind of data structure you want to get at the end.
source_csv.each do |row|
  split_a += row[:column_a].split(',').map(&:strip)
  split_b += row[:column_b].split(',').map(&:strip)
end

# The result
split_a
# => ["Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value6"]

split_b
# => ["Value3", "Value4", "Value5", "Value7", "Value8"]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want the output to be a CSV file I would suggest that it look like:

```
Column A|Column B
Value1|Value3
Value2|Value4
Value3|Value5
Value6|Value7
Value6|Value8
```

rather than

```
| Column A | Column B |
| Value1   | Value3   |
| Value2   | Value4   |
| Value3   | Value5   |
| Value6   | Value7   |
| Value6   | Value8   |
```

Enclosing each line with column separators and adding unnecessary spaces makes it unnecessarily difficult to extract the text of interest from the file.

---

Let's begin by creating the file you are given, though I have modified your example to make it easier to follow what is happening.

```
str=<<~_
| Column A   | Column B   |
| A1, A2, A3 | B1, B2, B3 |
| A4         | B4, B5     |
_
```

```
IN_NAME = 'in.csv'
OUT_NAME = 'out.csv'
```

```
File.write(IN_NAME, str)
  #=> 84
```

See [IO::write](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-write)<sup>1</sup>.

---

As the structure of this file resembles a CSV file only vaguely, I think it's easiest to read it using ordinary file I/O methods.

```
header, *body = IO.foreach(IN_NAME, chomp: true).with_object([]) do |line,arr|
  arr << line.gsub(/^\| *| *\|$/, '')
             .split(/ *\| */)
             .flat_map { |s| s.split(/, +/) }
end
```

(I provide an explanation of this calculation later.) This results in the following:

```
header
  #=> ["Column A", "Column B"]
body
  #=> [["A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3"], ["A4", "B4", "B5"]]
```

See [IO::foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach), [Enumerator#with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object) and [Enumerable#flat_map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map). Note that `foreach` without a block returns an enumerator that I have chained to `with_object`.

---

At this point it is convenient to compute the number of rows to be written to the output file after the header row.

```
mx = body.map(&:size).max
  #=> 6
```

Next we need to modify `body` to make it suitable for writing the output CSV file.

```
mod_body = Array.new(body.size) do |i|
  Array.new(mx) { |j| body[i][j] || body[i].last }
end.transpose
  #=> [["A1", "A4"], ["A2", "B4"], ["A3", "B5"], ["B1", "B5"],
  #    ["B2", "B5"], ["B3", "B5"]]
```

See [Array::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-c-new).

It is now a simple matter to write the output CSV file.

```
require 'csv'
```

```
CSV.open(OUT_NAME, "wb", col_sep: '|', headers: header, write_headers: true) do |csv|
  mod_body.each { |a| csv << a }
end
```

See [CSV::open](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-open).

Lastly, let's look at the file that was written.

```
puts File.read(OUT_NAME)
```

diplays

```
Column A|Column B
A1|A4
A2|B4
A3|B5
B1|B5
B2|B5
B3|B5
```

See [IO::read](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-read)<sup>1</sup>.

---

To explain the calculations made in

```
header, *body = IO.foreach(IN_NAME, chomp: true).with_object([]) do |line,arr|
  arr << line.gsub(/^\| *| *\|$/, '')
             .split(/ *\| */)
             .flat_map { |s| s.split(/, +/) }
end
```

it is easiest to run it with some `puts` statements inserted.

```
header, *body = IO.foreach(IN_NAME, chomp: true).with_object([]) do |line,arr|
  puts "line = #{line}"
  puts "arr = #{arr}"
  arr << line.gsub(/^\| *| *\|$/, '')
             .tap { |l| puts "  line after gsub = #{l}" }
             .split(/ *\| */)
             .tap { |a| puts "  array after split = #{a}" }
             .flat_map { |s| s.split(/, +/) }
             .tap { |a| puts "  array after flat_map = #{a}" }
end
  #=> [["Column A", "Column B"], ["A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3"],
  #    ["A4", "B4", "B5"]]
```

The following is displayed.

```
line = | Column A   | Column B   |
arr = []
  line after gsub = Column A   | Column B
  array after split = ["Column A", "Column B"]
  array after flat_map = ["Column A", "Column B"]
line = | A1, A2, A3 | B1, B2, B3 |
arr = [["Column A", "Column B"]]
  line after gsub = A1, A2, A3 | B1, B2, B3
  array after split = ["A1, A2, A3", "B1, B2, B3"]
  array after flat_map = ["A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3"]
line = | A4         | B4, B5     |
arr = [["Column A", "Column B"], ["A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3"]]
  line after gsub = A4         | B4, B5
  array after split = ["A4", "B4, B5"]
  array after flat_map = ["A4", "B4", "B5"]
```

<sup>1. `IO` methods are commonly invoked on `File`. That is permissible since `File.superclass #=> IO`</sup>.